# Get async data via @ViewChild

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

There is a **component Child** that makes an API request and gets some async data. This data is stored to the property `count`.

There is a **component Parent** that needs to get `count` value once it's gotten and do some actions with it.

**ParentComponent.ts**

```
@ViewChild('child', {static: false}) child: ChildComponent;
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.number = this.child.count;
}
...
```

**Question**

Since the `count` property is async, inside `ngAfterViewInit()` I receive `undefined`. How to get updated value? Maybe `ngOnChanges()` or something else should work for me?

Comment: https://medium.com/@nishu0505/using-viewchild-in-angular-de1854a51872

Comment: Are you using the child component in the template? If yes, a simple `EventEmitter` would suffice your requirement.

Comment: Could you post your template (HTML)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting undefined is that you're expecting the value before the async data is made available (when your async request has finished I assume). You can use an [Event Emitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) to send the data to the parent. This way, you can set `number` in the parent to be the value of `count` only when you have it. I also recommend reading the [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) guide in the official docs.

1. Register the event emitter in your child component

**ChildComponent**

```
@Output() countChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

2. When you receive the data, you can emit the data to the parent:

```
// ...Logic that gets the data
this.countChanged.emit(this.count);
//...
```

3. In the parent template, you can then bind to the child component and listen to child events.

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<child-component (countChanged)="doSomethingWithCount($event)></child-component>`
```

**Parent Component**

```
public doSomethingWithCount(count: number):void {
    this.number = count;
    //. . . More logic
}
```